# Returning user friendly error messages when the JSON value is incorrect?

Tags: scala, scala-cats, http4s

Currently my API endpoint works fine in the happy path if the JSON value corresponds to my case class correctly.

How can I return a user friendly message when it doesn't?

```
case class UpdateUserRequest (
   registrationStatus: String,
   level: Int
)
```

For example, say the value level has to be between 10 and 20.
And the String value for registraition status has to be either "a", "b" or "c".

```
case updateUser @ PUT -> Root / "users" as user => {
    for {
        updateReq <- updateUser.req.as[UpdateUserRequest]
       ....
       apiResponse <- Ok(200, true, "")
    } yield apiResponse
}
```

My response object is like:

```
case class ApiResponse(
  statusCode: Int,
  success: boolean,
  errorMessage: String
)
```

Comment: You may use `attempAs`

Comment: is that http4s or cats specific? I can't seem to find that

Comment: Is part of `Response` you can use `attemptAs` instead of `as` to get an `Either` and handle that.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I tried using attemptAs, do I need to pass it the types explicitly?

Comment: Yes, just like `as`

Comment: How is your `EntityDecoder` defined?